# How does Nginx pass SSL encrypted data to a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

Suppose I have a setup running my Rails app with Unicorn and using Nginx as the reverse proxy. When Nginx is configured to handle SSL does that mean it passes the encrypted data to my Rails app directly unchanged or does it decrypt it and then send that to my Rails app, so that my Rails app sees unencrypted data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called nginx ssl termination. The data is already decrypted by nginx and the upstream rails app just need to deal with unencrypted data, i.e., you rails app should just listen to port 80 (http) and in your reverse proxy setup, you should have

```
proxy_pass http://rails_app_domain;
```

NOT

```
proxy_pass https://rails_app_domain;
```

Comment: Which do I want? Do I want ssl termination or do I want nginx to pass the encrypted data unchanged?

Comment: You want nginx to decrypt and pass unencrypted data to rails.  Nginx should handle all the decryption (inbound traffic) and encryption (outbound) - it's done in C and very very fast.  You don't want Ruby/Rails to deal with encrypted data.

Comment: As the rails app is on the same server or inside a LAN, it's safe to terminate ssl in nginx, and leave rails app do whatever it's good at: serving the content.