# What does force_ssl do in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673328/how-does-nginx-pass-ssl-encrypted-data-to-a-rails-app) I found out that I should be setting nginx ssl termination and not having Rails process encrypted data.

Then why does the following exist?

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

I see this commented out in the production config file. But if the expectation is that nginx will handle all the ssl stuff so that my rails app doesn't deal with encrypted data then what does `config.force_ssl = true` do?

Should I leave it commented out in production if I know I will always be using nginx?

Answer (score 86):

It doesn't *just* force your browser to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.  It also sets your cookies to be marked "secure", and it enables [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), each of which are very good protections against SSL stripping.

Even though HTTPS protects your app at "https://example.com/yourapp" against MITM attacks, if someone gets between your client and your server they can rather easily get you to visit "http://example.com/yourapp". With neither of the above protections, your browser will happily send the session cookie to the person doing the MITM.

Comment: The source of [force_ssl](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb) contains no indication of HSTS being enabled by this option

Comment: @agios This is a separate per-controller `force_ssl` property. The `force_ssl` config variable, which installs the `Rack::SSL` middleware, which [does enable HSTS by default](https://github.com/josh/rack-ssl/blob/master/lib/rack/ssl.rb#L61).

Comment: @agios you're looking in the wrong place: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/794252d70990162d14da17ee854ad353e74297ee/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb

Comment: it sounds like `config.force_ssl = true` should be the default, why did the rails team  comment it out as default?

Answer (score 74):

Setting `config.force_ssl` includes `ActionDispatch::SSL`. The `ActionDispatch::SSL` docs describe the functionality as follows (emphases added for clarity):

> See the includes [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b326e82dc012d81e9698cb1f402502af1788c1e9/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L14) and the docs for ActionDispatch::SSL [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html).

#### DOCS

This middleware is added to the stack when `config.force_ssl = true`, and is passed the options set in `config.ssl_options`. It does three jobs to enforce secure HTTP requests:

1. TLS redirect: **Permanently redirects http:// requests to https://**
   with the same URL host, path, etc. Enabled by default. Set `config.ssl_options`
   to modify the destination URL
   (e.g. `redirect: { host: "secure.widgets.com", port: 8080 }`), or set
   `redirect: false` to disable this feature.
2. Secure cookies: **Sets the `secure` flag on cookies** to tell browsers they
   mustn't be sent along with http:// requests. Enabled by default. Set
   `config.ssl_options` with `secure_cookies: false` to disable this feature.
3. HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS): **Tells the browser to remember
   this site as TLS-only and automatically redirect non-TLS requests**.
   Enabled by default. Configure `config.ssl_options` with `hsts: false` to disable.
   Set `config.ssl_options` with `hsts: { … }` to configure HSTS:

   - `expires`: How long, in seconds, these settings will stick. Defaults to
     `180.days` (recommended). The minimum required to qualify for browser
     preload lists is `18.weeks`.
   - `subdomains`: Set to `true` to tell the browser to apply these settings
     to all subdomains. This protects your cookies from interception by a
     vulnerable site on a subdomain. Defaults to `true`.
   - `preload`: Advertise that this site may be included in browsers'
     preloaded HSTS lists. HSTS protects your site on every visit *except the
     first visit* since it hasn't seen your HSTS header yet. To close this
     gap, browser vendors include a baked-in list of HSTS-enabled sites.
     Go to https://hstspreload.appspot.com to submit your site for inclusion.
     To turn off HSTS, omitting the header is not enough. Browsers will remember the original HSTS directive until it expires. Instead, use the header to tell browsers to expire HSTS immediately. Setting `hsts: false` is a shortcut for `hsts: { expires: 0 }`.

Requests can opt-out of redirection with `exclude`:

```
config.ssl_options = { redirect: { exclude: -> request { request.path =~ /healthcheck/ } } }
```

Comment: "Requests can opt-out of redirection with `exclude`" - Warning: this feature was only added recently in Rails 5, so won't work for those of us on Rails 4.2 or below

Comment: I believe the `exclude` global options was available a long time before Rails 5, so it's slightly different syntaxt: `config.ssl_options = { exclude: proc { |env| env['PATH_INFO'].start_with?('/healthcheck/') } }` — https://serverfault.com/a/517401

Answer (score 13):

This setting forces HTTPS by redirecting HTTP requests to their HTTPS counterparts. So a browser visiting `http://domain.com/path` will be redirected to `https://domain.com/path`.

Leaving the setting commented out would allow both protocols.

You still have to configure your web server to handle HTTPS requests.

Comment: But if you enable HTTPS at nginx level (by redirecting everything to HTTPS via `redirect 301 https:...`), wouldn't EVERYTHING be going through https, thus `config.force_ssl = true` doesn't really do anything (since nothing will ever be http)? Or is there a deeper security reason here?

Comment: @TristanTao yes, that would work just as well. But even then, I would leave `config.force_ssl` enabled, just in case someone is removing the redirect from the web server's config.

Comment: be careful doh, config.force_ssl is bit different than force_ssl in controller in terms of securing cookies against session hijacking more here: http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/14-config-force_ssl-is-different-than-controller-force_ssl

Comment: also note, that having both `config.force_ssl` and `add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=...;` will result in 2 `Strict-Transport-Security` headers

Answer (score 6):

It forces all communication with the server to be encrypted and use SSL, i.e. through HTTPS.

When you include it in a controller that controller will only accept HTTPS requests.

Helpful links:

1. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html
2. http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionController/ForceSSL
3. http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?view=comments