# Force https in a Rails 4 route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What's the proper way to enforce https in a rails 4 route?

For example I would expect to be able to do something like:

```
get 'success' => 'ssl#success', :ssl_only => true
```

But that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `force_ssl` to force `http://site/success` to redirect to `https://site/success`. Please refer to the documentation for [force_ssl](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html).

```
class SSLController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl only: :success # see docs for more options
end
```

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676596/what-does-force-ssl-do-in-rails).)

Comment: Yes, I knew about that one, it seems like there should be a rails 4 trick to forcing it in the route.

Comment: I don't quite understand. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `https://.../ssl/success`

```
 scope constraints: { protocol: 'https' } do
  get 'success', to: 'ssl#success', as: 'success' 
 end
```

or

```
get 'success', to: 'ssl#success', as: 'success', constraints: { protocol: 'https' }
```

Comment: No I want https://mysite.com/success to go to ssl#success. This answer isn't working for me.

Comment: sorry I am not getting is ssl  your controller? and success is your action?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this to work with:

```
get 'success', to: 'ssl#success', constraints: {protocol: /https/}
```

Comment: hope it is same as my post ...excpt 'https' to /https/

Comment: I know, it's a small thing. My hunch is that the protocol is actually 'https://' or something and this is why the regex works but not the string.

Comment: Doesn't work for you maybe, but his answer is the correct one and it lead you to your answer. I think that would have been fair.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked by adding "force_ssl" in the application_controller.rb.