# Set session cookie as secure in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have Rails application, which is running on https.
My application session cookies are http-only.
How to set those cookies as secure and https-only in rails?

Answer (score 13):

## Rails 3/4

If you want to flag the session cookie as secure, in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`, set the secure flag:

```
Demo::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
  key: '_demo_session',
  secret: "your secret",
  secure: Rails.env.production?, # flags cookies as secure only in production
  httponly: true # should be true by default for all cookies
```

If you want to flag **all** cookies as secure, add `config.force_ssl = true` in the desired `config/environments/*.rb` file.  This feature adds other functionality to your Rails app, summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676596/what-does-force-ssl-do-in-rails).

Comment: @Srinivas Yadav I also created a minimalist rack middleware you can use to set the secure flag on all your session cookies: https://github.com/jmera/secure_cookies

Comment: `config.force_ssl = true` unless you do the SSL via your load balancer

Comment: I am using Nginx and when I set `secure: true` the cookie doesn't appear as secure in the browser dev-cookies view. I wonder why.

Comment: Just an FYI for future readers, you can also specify `same_site: "Strict"`.