# Force Ruby on Rails app to load on HTTPS version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, url-rewriting

I have an HTTP and HTTPS version of my Ruby on Rails running, and if someone accesses through the HTTP one, I want to automatically reload the HTTPS version.

I have done this before on Apache with .httaccess. How can I do it on Rails?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting `config.force_ssl = true` in `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your production.rb file (or whichever env you are forcing ssl) add

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve that by:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl if: :ssl_enabled?

  private

  def ssl_enabled?
    %w(staging production).include?(Rails.env)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by putting the below code in `config/applcation.rb`

```
#config/application.rb
config.force_ssl = true
```

Check this [***blog***](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/) and this [***SO***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676596/what-does-force-ssl-do-in-rails) post for more info.