# Why isn't `config.force_ssl = true` default for production rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676596/what-does-force-ssl-do-in-rails), it sounds like config.force_ssl = true should be the default, why did the rails team not make it default when creating a new app (inside `config/environments/production.rb`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because not all servers will use `ssl`. You need to set `config.force_ssl = true` only if you're using valid `ssl` cert.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running a test instance in production mode on your local system, which might not require SSL. So it's better to let the user decide if they require SSL or not.

Comment: When you say user, do you mean the developer who use rails?

Comment: Yes. The person who develops the app.