# What can be the reason for 'config.force_ssl = false' in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

I found that `config.force_ssl = false` in *config/application.rb*, and nowhere it is defined as true, though the domain have SSL certificate. will there be any specific reason for setting it as false? or is there any alternate way to do the same?

Reference [What does 'force_ssl' do in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676596/what-does-force-ssl-do-in-rails)

Answer (score 2):

If your Rails application is behind a load balancer or other proxy, and that proxy is responsible for providing SSL/TLS (e.g. [as described here for Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/)), then that proxy, not your Rails app, is responsible for ensuring HTTP requests are redirected to HTTPS, and your Rails app shouldn't have to think about SSL/TLS at all. In that case `config.force_ssl` should be `false`, even in production.

(In development and test it should also be `false`, because in those environments you don't want to have to mess with certificates etc. -- although it [can be done](https://puma.io/puma/#self-signed-ssl-certificates-via-the-localhost-gem-for-development-use-) if you really insist on it -- which is why that's what you're more likely to see in `environment.rb`, even if it's overridden in `environments/production.rb`.)

Answer (score 0):

SSL enables to have all the network request to your application using HTTPS.. So if `config.force_ssl` is set as true, then you need to have a SSL certificate and all your request will go through HTTPS

Comment: The concerned app domain have SSL certificate.

Comment: @AmarnathJoshi then you can configure your web server to use that certificate and change the rails conf to use HTPPS