# docker automatically redirects to https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, http, redirect

I've dockerized a ruby app and am trying to view it locally but every browser I have used redirects from http://0.0.0.0:3000 to https://0.0.0.0:3000 so I'm getting the browser error

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection 0.0.0.0 sent an invalid response.
```

I've tried clearing the cache, browsing history etc. rebooted, and included HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect in docker compose environment.

I can access the site from rails server using http://127.0.0.1:3000 which doesn't redirect and suggests it's something in the dockerfile or docker compose that is doing it. I'm new to docker so forgive me I'm missing something obvious.

Here's the dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.7-alpine3.16 AS builder

ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE 1

# RUN mkdir /app
# WORKDIR /app

# Install required libraries on Alpine
# note: build-base required for nokogiri gem
# note: postgresql-dv required for pg gem
RUN apk update && \
    apk add tzdata postgresql-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-client && \
    apk add nodejs yarn && \
    apk add build-base && \
    gem install rails bundler && \
    # Throw errors if Gemfile has been modified since Gemfile.lock
    bundle config --global frozen 1

# Copy Gemfile so we can cache gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

# Install Ruby gems
RUN bundle install --without development test

# Copy all application files
COPY . .

# Precompile assets
RUN bundle exec rails assets:precompile && \
    bundle exec rails webpacker:compile


RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]


EXPOSE 3000
```

Here's the docker compose

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  rails:

    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    env_file:
      - rails.env
    environment:
      HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect
      DB_USERNAME: xxxxxxxx
      DB_PASSWORD: .env
      DB_DATABASE: xxxxxx_production
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_HOST: db
      RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 5
      
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "db"
  db:
    image: postgres:13.9-alpine
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect
      POSTGRES_USER: xxxxxxx
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata  
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

and the entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Note: !/bin/sh must be at the top of the line,
# Alpine doesn't have bash so we need to use shell.
# Docker entrypoint script.
# Don't forget to give this file execution rights via `chmod +x entrypoint.sh`
# which I've added to the Dockerfile but you could do this manually instead.

# Wait until Postgres is ready before running the next step.
while ! pg_isready -q -h $DB_HOST -p $DB_PORT -U $DB_USERNAME
do
  echo "$(date) - waiting for database to start."
  sleep 2
done

# If the database exists, migrate. Otherwise setup (create and migrate)
echo "Running database migrations..."
bundle exec rails db:migrate 2>/dev/null || bundle exec rails db:create db:migrate
echo "Finished running database migrations."

# Remove a potentially pre-existing server.pid for Rails.
echo "Deleting server.pid file..."
rm -f /tmp/pids/server.pid

# Start the server.
echo "Starting rails server..."
bundle exec rails server
```

Any advice much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker doesn't redirect http to https. There is one possible option in Ruby on Rails. In your environment file for production settings, you're forcing ssl.

```rb
config.force_ssl = true
```

This option forces your browser to use https instead to http. This means the rails server sends a redirect to the browser to https. But your server is not configured for https, so the described errors occurs.

References:

- [What does force_ssl do in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676596/what-does-force-ssl-do-in-rails)
- https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods/force_ssl

Comment: Thanks. This worked! Is it a good idea to disable this permanently though? I suppose I could always reset it at deployment. I'm just wondering what is good practice for this kind of thing.

Comment: It's about how do you provide ssl. We currently using a third party reverse proxy before our application server.
Perhaps you can mark my answer as a successful answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` because your app tells you that that's the address that it's listening on.

However, 0.0.0.0 is not the IP address of the service. It's the address that it's 'bound' to. And 0.0.0.0 means that it'll accept connections from anywhere.

The actual address of your service is `http://localhost:3000/` or, as you've discovered, `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`. The two addresses are equivalent.

Read [this](https://medium.com/pragmatic-programmers/binding-the-rails-serve-r-to-ip-addresses-3812ee4959e0) for more information.

Comment: I've tried this. If I launch rails server it says 'Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000' and will connect in a browser to this address. If I launch my docker container it says 'Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000'. No matter what http address I try and connect on, the browser will redirect it to a https equivalent. I've tried this on 4 different browsers. Even with nothing launched browsers are redirecting to https. I'm wondering if this is something in the OS that is set (OSX Ventura 13.1). It's like it's a global setting and for some reason rails server overrides it but docker doesn't.

Comment: In the 3rd paragraph in your post you say that `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` doesn't redirect. Now you say that everything redirects. I'm confused.

Comment: Opening a http address after rails s is called does not redirect. If the rails s command is not called then it redirects. Opening a docker container for example at the same http address will redirect to https.